# julia vector space model package?

Tags: vector, julia

just starting with Julia and the jetson nano. I want to look into using the 128 gpu's in implementing a vector space model. I understand that Julia has many packages but I can't find one for vector space modelling. I'm pretty sure one exists and I am not searching in the right place. If anyone knows a julia package that has the basis for building a rudimentary vector space model from a set of documents I would be grateful to hear about it. 
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a vector space model in this context? Documents as in text documents?

Comment: hi there @FredrikBagge  thanks for the question. Yep actual text documents. I am looking into using the Word2Vec.jl library BUT with the added feature of handing off the work to the Jetson Nano 128 gpu's.  It seems an approach ideally suited to the jetson nano.

Comment: There is the following packages for you to explore
https://github.com/domluna/Glove.jl
https://github.com/JuliaText/Word2Vec.jl
https://github.com/JuliaText/Embeddings.jl

Comment: thanks @FredrikBagge  sorry to have taken so long to get back to this. REALLY helpful and I look forwards to seeing how I get on with the "new" language.